# How to get repeated value in group

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find number of repeated value in group using single select query.
I can't use the column in group by for which I want to find number of occurrence in some group.

e.g.

```
obsid    Name      Value                 
1        Ronak     120
2        Ronak     125   
3        Ronak     120                      
4        Pankti    130                      
5        Pankti    130
6        Sanket    140     
7        Aakash    140
8        Unnat     120
```

Now I want to develop select query  in mysql that give me below result

```
obsid    Name      Value     Value_occurrence             
1        Ronak     120       2
2        Ronak     125       1              
4        Pankti    130       2              
6        Sanket    140       1
7        Aakash    140       1
8        Unnat     120       1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the desired columns and use `COUNT` to count the rows in each group:

```
SELECT MIN(`obsid`) AS `obsid`, `Name`, `Value`, COUNT(*) AS Value_occurrence             
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY `Name`, `Value`
```

Try [this online demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/723c0/2) which shows your example data and the results for the above query.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT min(obsid) AS obsid, Name, Value, COUNT(*) AS Value_occurence
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Name, Value
```